# Converting multiple hex color to image

Tags: php, image, converters, pixel

is there a function that will convert hex colors to image and save it as png?
example :

```
   $pixelrow1 ["000000","000000","000000"];
   $pixelrow2 ["000000","FFFFFF","000000"];
   $pixelrow3 ["FF0000","00FF00","0000FF"];
   function convert_to_image($row1,$row2,$row3,$path_to_save) {
   // Some function
   }
   convert_to_image($pixelrow1,$pixelrow2,$pixelrow3,"c:/image.png");
```

I really have no idea if is it possible or not, but i'm pretty sure that its possible because you can make image using php

The output should return like this :
[image]

Comment: what you want convert image thats fine but $row1,$row2,$row3 have 3 colors and how it use in image?

Comment: i edited the question body, can you recheck it?

Comment: Please tell me your data are in an array - rather than in things like `$pixelrow1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, but hopefully your variables have more sensible names and you can use a loop:

```
<?php
   $im    = imagecreate(3,3);
   $black = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0); 
   $white = imagecolorallocate($im,0xff,0xff,0xff); 
   $red   = imagecolorallocate($im,0xff,0,0); 
   $green = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0xff,0); 
   $blue  = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0xff); 

   # First row
   imagesetpixel($im,0,0,$black);
   imagesetpixel($im,1,0,$black);
   imagesetpixel($im,2,0,$black);

   # Second row
   imagesetpixel($im,0,0,$black);
   imagesetpixel($im,1,1,$white);
   imagesetpixel($im,2,1,$black);

   # Third row
   imagesetpixel($im,0,2,$red);
   imagesetpixel($im,1,2,$green);
   imagesetpixel($im,2,2,$blue);

   imagepng($im,"result.png");
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is not saving the data into the file you want.

The real problem is saving the data IN png format.

You should read how png saves the data.

Or you can play a little with PHP image resources.
Maybe this snippet of code can give you some advice:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(1, 1);
// Creates a 1x1 image resource

$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
// Adds a red background color to the only pixel in the image.

imagepng($im);
// Sends the image to the browser.

imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

If you wanna take a look at all the functions for the images:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php